# Is there something wrong with my propensity score matching code?

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

I'm using propensity score matching to see if there are any trends in my data with RStudio. From my understanding, all of the covariates are supposed to generate a standard mean difference so I can see if they are balanced well and move forward with the regression. My issue is that when I generate the summary, I can only see one covariate, 'age' in the distance column, and it lists out every age I have in the dataset instead of the other four covariates in the data set.

This is the code I'm using:

```r
opgt2014 <- data.frame(X2014_Binary_Data)

library(sandwich)
library(MatchIt)
library(lmtest)

match_obj <- matchit(Chief.Complaint ~ Age + Sex + Triage + Mode.Arr,
    data = opgt2014, method = "nearest", distance ="glm", ratio = 1,
    replace = FALSE)

summary(match_obj)
```

And this is an example of what each column of the data looks like:

Age: 2Y 06M | 10M 20D | 36 | 42
Sex: 1 | 0 | 1 | 1
Triage: 1 | 2 | 3 | 1
Chief Complaint: 0 | 0 | 1 | 0
Mode Arr: 3 | 4 | 0 | 1

Any idea what is going on here? I'm new to coding, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't provided us with a reproducible example, so it's hard to say without looking at a simple example of your data (or a made up example that exactly reflects the characteristics and structure of your input dataset `X2014_Binary_Data`).  But the only reason I can think of the summary call would display every age in your dataset is if it is coded as a factor variable.  You'd almost certainly want this coded as an numeric.  If you can update your question with a dump of `str(X2014_Binary_Data)`, if you can't provide some data, I can probably provide more information.

Comment: But a good start would be to recode your Age as numeric.  The safest way for you to probably do this is with `X2014_Binary_Data$Age %>% as.character(.) %>% as.numeric()`. or `as.numeric(as.character(X2014_Binary_Data$age))`